# How can you call different versions of similar extension methods with kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following functions to simulate the ternary operator for kotlin

```
fun Boolean.then(action: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    if (this)
        action.invoke()
    return this
}

fun Boolean.otherwise(action: () -> Unit) {
    if (!this)
        action.invoke()
}

fun <T> Boolean.then(func: () -> T): T? {
    if (this)
        return func.invoke()
    return null
}

fun <T> T?.otherwise(action: () -> T): T {
    return this ?: action.invoke()
}
```

they are supposed to be used like this :

```
(check).then { doHello() }.otherwise { doWorld() }

val answer = (check).then { "hello" }.otherwise { "world" }
```

however when I try to assign a value using the above operators like this:

```
 val visibility: Int = (show).then { View.VISIBLE }.alt { View.GONE }
```

I get an error saying that the required reply was Int but it actually got Unit which means that it called the first version of the methods instead of the second

Other than renaming the methods (when I changed the first two to thenDo and otherwiseDo it worked), can I write the above code in some way so that the compiler will know to call the second version?

Comment: What's wrong with `val visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE`?

Comment: or if your condition is actually more complex: `yourObject.takeIf { /* complex condition */ }?.let { View.VISIBLE /* or the transformation if condition holds */ } ?: View.GONE /* default value if condition doesn't hold */`

Comment: val visibility: Int = (show).then<Int> { View.VISIBLE }.alt { View.GONE }

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it I just like the ternary operator and wanted it to apply to my code. Also thank you @Roland I didn't know about `takeIf` I'll read more about it

Comment: also thank you @Eugene that seems to work, unfortunatelly I changed the functions to infix, so that doesn't seem to work with those, thanks for the reply though

Comment: If `then`'s block returns a null in some cases, your code will compile, but probably not do what you want.

Comment: I'm very uncomfortable about what you're trying to do here, which is basically to build your own language on top of Kotlin.  That's fine for DSLs, but Kotlin's `if` expression already does exactly what you want.  Your approach makes it harder to understand for other developers, and for IDEs and other tools, and also for _you_ to read other people's code (as you surely will have to).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah you're right if the (func: () -> T) returns null it will also trigger the alt method which I do not want, I guess I have to be careful about that

Comment: @gidds I'm not using this in production code, at work we still use Java and C#, I'm using this for my own projects,  if I had to do this in a work environment I'd definitely have to discuss it first with my co-workers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need both overloads. If you remove the ones that return `Unit`, then both your lines of code work:

```
(check).then { doHello() }.otherwise { doWorld() }
val answer = (check).then { "hello" }.otherwise { "world" }
```

That's because the first line, where the lambdas return `Unit`, e.g. `doHello()`, can still use the generic versions of `then` and `otherwise`, as they are still considered functions with a return value, namely `Unit`.

Although I agree with some the comments above: do you really need this? Why not just use `if`, which is an expression which returns a value (like the ternary operator).  See discussion [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116) for more info.

Comment: you're right I can remove the first version, unit is still considered a T. as for why, I started it as an excercise to see if I can do it, and now I just like the syntax better, also I changed the funs to infix so I can now write `(check) then {doThis()} otherwise {doThat()}`